# Combinatorial analysis and probability problem

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Given the letters of "MESALVA", it's selected 4 letters and made anagrams with it. What's the probability of forming a anagram with the letter "A"?

In document the answer is 80%, but what is the math process to this result?

I tried (7×6×5×4 - 5×4×3×2)/(7×6×5×4)

But I get ≈ 85% as result

Comment: the wording isn't clear.  You seem to be interpreting the problem as asking for the probability that, out of $4$ letters chosen uniformly at random, at least one of them is $A$.  But the problem asks about anagrams and, while most choices of $4$ letters give rise to $4!=24$ anagrams, those with two $A's$  give fewer.  It's not clear if we are meant to take that into account or not.

Comment: What's the probability of the letter 'a' on the anagrams for taking into account and not taking into account?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you count them.  Are we saying that it is twice as likely to get $AMES$ as it is to get $MESL$ (since there are two $A's$)?  Depending on how you count that, I either get $75\%$ or $83.\overline 3\%$ (though I did it hastily and might have made a mistake).  Maybe the writers were just speaking loosely.

Comment: What is the calculus behind the result of 83.3%?

Comment: There are $\binom 54=5$ ways to choose them with no $A's$.  There are $2\times \binom 53=20$ ways to choose them with exactly one $A$ (assuming we count the two $A's$ separately).  That gives rise to $25$ ways to do it such that all $24$ anagrams are distinct.  Then there are $\binom 52=10$ ways to choose them with two $A's$.  Those only have $2\times \binom 42=12$ anagrams. so the probability of choosing an anagram with at least one $A$ is $\frac {20\times 24+10\times 12}{25\times 24 +10\times 12}=\frac {600}{720}=.8\overline 3$.

Comment: If we don't double the probability for those with one $A$ then it's the same calculation only this time there are only $10$ anagrams with exactly one $A$.

Comment: @LucasR. Your ~85% result assumes that there are 7-choose-4 possible outcomes... but that double-counts results like $A_1 A_2 E L$ and $A_2 A_1 E L$ as distinct possibilities despite both representing the same 'anagram' of $A A E L$.

Comment: How do I solve this problem? Dividing by 2! ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question means pick $4$ *distinct* letters, in which case there are $5$ with no A and $10$ with either A, so $\frac{10+10}{10+10+5}=\frac45$.